# How to create crosstab for a dataframe that has a dictionary within a cell using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a dictionary within each cell. The key is

```
 AA          BB                     
ddd   {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
eee   {'a': 2, 'b': 5}
ddd   {'a': 1, 'b': 6}
```

I would like to reshape this table so that it gets grouped by column AA and the headers become dict keys and dict values are summed. Something like this.

```
            'a'   'b'
ddd          4     10  
eee          2      5
```

if it helps, the original table started with cells of column BB being a string (e.g  `'a, a, a, b, b, b, b'`). that was converted to a list and then eventually a dictionary using the counter library to get there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Data frame constructor re-build you dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df.BB.tolist(),index=df.AA).sum(level=0)
Out[332]: 
     a   b
AA        
ddd  4  10
eee  2   5
```